# I downloaded a web page code on my windows, and uploaded it on my linux apache server . Why does it miss picture?

Tags: linux, apache, web

I downloaded a web page code on my windows, and uploaded it on my linux apache server. Index.html and picture  are int the same directory.

Why does it miss picture?

Answer (score 1):

If you have uploaded pictures too on linux server check below:

Full path in index.html code move images on correct path.

Check permissions of image files.

Check error logs of apache for more detail of issue.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I found  I went wrong in apache configuration .  Good luck .